# EE 1.13.1 - Target Rule Index cause 'Integrity constraint violation'

Tags: index, catalog-rules, ee-1.13.1.0

I'm having the following exception on EE 1.13.1

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxx' for key '5B1C775075460366570ABDA2839BC68A' in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
```

It looks something goes wrong with the Category Rules index:

1. According to the exception information the issue starts from `app/code/core/Enterprise/TargetRule/Model/Resource/Index/Abstract.php(213)`
2. key `5B1C775075460366570ABDA2839BC68A` is actually an index of this table `enterprise_targetrule_index_related`

Any Idea ?
I'm actually debugging the above issue and I will share more info if I find something.

**UPDATE**

I have provided a solution below.
It will be great if someone with more experience can confirm if try catch is fine ( usually it is not advisable to use try catch in the business logic ) or transaction is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 213 that trigger the exception is the one that try to do the `INSERT`

An initial `SELECT` check if a record with `$targetruleId` exist, if not Magento try to `INSERT` it.
In some occasion (maybe because some concurrent access to the same page)
a record is created, just after the select, just before the insert ...

If you need a official fix Magento has has patch for it.